# How to send post data with AJAX, current solution not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So I have a button where I want to use ajax to send post data to a PHP document then reload the page.

Here is the button:

```html
  <button value="ON" id="send" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm">ON</button><br>
```

Here is the AJAX

```js
    <script>
    $('#send').click(function() {
    var val1 = $('Online').text();;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'stat.php',
        data: { stat: val1 },
        success: function(response) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
});
}
    </script>
```

Comment: did you check in console for any error

Comment: could you show any error in the console?

Comment: Yes I'm getting data is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please remove

> window.location.reload();

You are not getting reposnse from ajax because the page is reload before getting data

OR, if you want to reload the page after page success use below code:

```
  <script>
    $('#send').click(function() {
    var val1 = "asdas";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'stat.php',
        data: { stat: val1 },
        success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);

        if(response){ // if true (1)
         setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
           location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
      }, 5000); 
       }

        }
    });
});

    </script>
```

This will help you for sure!

Comment: I have removed that however I need to refresh the page automatically to update a value in the code

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Comment: I have another problem, I'm getting the error of: data is not defined

Comment: oh ya you have to use response insttead of data as we are passing response in success function..i have update my answer check now

Comment: Thank you however, the page is not reloading

Comment: I have update my code and 5000 for 5 sec you can use your time when you want to load the page

Comment: It still does not seem to reload

Comment: well its working for me try to use less time like use 800 and then check

Answer (score 0):

you can use the new way of using `$.ajax` using `done()` method that will be triggered if the request is successfully sent according to the jQuery [official doc documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

assuming the element  of `val1` is like bellow

```js
$('#send').on('click', function() {
  var val1 = $('#online').text();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/stat.php',
    data: {
      stat1: val1
    },
  }).done(function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="online" value="test">
```

Comment: I'm not attempting to send user input, my goal is to have a user press a button, ajax sends post data to my php script, my php script puts it in a table, and when reloaded the info is there, and the php side is good however the AJAX is the problem

Comment: ok I just remind you that If you'll be upgrading jQuery version above 1.8,the jqXHR object (returned by $.ajax) `success` will be replaced with `done`, error with `fail` and complete with `always`.